# Cross-Domain AJAX Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make a cross-domain AJAX call with the latest jQuery for the Twitch.TV API and I'm getting an error.

Code:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    url: "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/games?q=star&type=suggest",
    success: function (responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log("in");
        var data = JSON.parse(responseData['AuthenticateUserResult']);
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('POST failed.');
    }
});
```

Error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/games?q=star&type=suggest. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://codeeplus.net' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: I've actually seen that post and it didn't work for me at all.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/  and take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: *What* didn't work for you? Reverse proxy should work fine. twitch.tv also supports JSONP, just add `callback=whatever` to the query string.

Comment: @user2812028 – None of the half dozen options worked for you?! That seems unlikely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need JSONP for cross-browser requests. The link you gave me works fine with getJSON jquery function.

for streams: **http://jsfiddle.net/82wNq/27/**

for games: **http://jsfiddle.net/82wNq/25/**

```
$.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/games?q=star&type=suggest&callback=?", function (data) {
    $.each(data.games, function (index, item) {
        $("<div>").html(item.name).appendTo("#content");
        $("<img>").attr("src", item.box.medium).appendTo("#content");
    });
});
```

Comment: This worked! But how would I do this with /search/streams instead of /search/games ? I'm guessing you need to change data.games to something else, I tried with just data and that didn't work. Any ideas? @thenewseattle